How the pull request is automatically closed if any one of the job fails in the github action?
name: Lint and Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [20.x]
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v4
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run lint
      

To implement a GitHub Actions workflow where linting is automatically run when a pull request is created, and the pull request is automatically closed if the linting fails

What is your specific problem with doing that? So far you're just linting. How to run a step conditionally (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/writing-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsif)? Close a PR (https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_close)? Break down the problem and do some research.

I changed my workflow by adding , "- run: npm run lint
- name: Close PR if Lint Fails
if: failure()
run: |
gh pr close ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }} --comment "Closing this PR because linting failed."
But,the pull request is not being automatically closed when the linting fails, even though the workflow runs as expected. The problem could be related to how the pull request is being closed programmatically.

GitHub CLI needs a token and this token needs a permission to act on pull requests. I have modified the workflow by configuring default GITHUB_TOKEN with required permissions at the job level - to pull a repo and to write to PRs. I have also configured GH_TOKEN for GitHb CLI.
See modified workflow with these changes:
name: Lint and Test

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      pull-requests: write
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [20.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run lint
      - name: Close PR if Lint Fails
        if: failure()
        run: gh pr close ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

